# Building Complex Models Using Functional API (for multiple inputs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I was writing code for regression model (for multiple inputs) in google colab using `tensorflow.keras`

- First, I created 2 inputs `input_A` and `input_B`
- Next, I created Dense layer with 30 neurons and using the "relu" activation function as soon as  I created I call it like a function
- Then created second Dense layer with same activation function and again call it like function
- Next, created `concatenate()` layer and again call it as a function
- Then created output layer with single neuron
- At the end, I created Keras model, specifying which inputs and outputs to use

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

example=3

# for multiple inputs
input_A = keras.layers.Input(shape=[example])
input_B = keras.layers.Input(shape=[example])
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(30,activation="relu")(input_B)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(30,activation="relu")(hidden1)
cancat = keras.layers.concatenate([input_A,hidden2])
output = keras.layers.Dense(1)(concat)
model  = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_A, input_B], outputs=[output])
```

and got following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-f85c981028d6> in <module>()
      6 cancat = keras.layers.concatenate([input_A,hidden2])
      7 output = keras.layers.Dense(1)(concat)
----> 8 model  = keras.models.Model([input_A, input_B], outputs=[output])

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable, **kwargs)
    107     generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, {})
    108     super(Functional, self).__init__(name=name, trainable=trainable)
--> 109     self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    110 
    111   @tf.__internal__.tracking.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs)
    191     # Keep track of the network's nodes and layers.
    192     nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, _ = _map_graph_network(
--> 193         self.inputs, self.outputs)
    194     self._network_nodes = nodes
    195     self._nodes_by_depth = nodes_by_depth

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    982                              'The following previous layers '
    983                              'were accessed without issue: ' +
--> 984                              str(layers_with_complete_input))
    985         for x in tf.nest.flatten(node.outputs):
    986           computable_tensors.add(id(x))

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "dense_4". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I don't think I did anything wrong, so why is this error coming up?

Comment: Can you attach the output of model.summary() ?

Comment: @AlexWaygood First,thankyou for taking intrest in my question. I realised that i made sily mistack i created concatenate and assigned to "cancat"  but while using output as a function i gaved concat. this concat is somthing that i used for different model because of that colab not raised name error and that concat is on different input and hidden layer.